# Find next on RichTextBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I tried a code for Find next in `richtextbox` but seems like it's not getting me to the next string found. It stops at the first string even if there are more. Here is code example:

```
    void Button12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string searchText = textBox2.Text ;
        int findPos = 0;
        try
        {
            string s = textBox2.Text;
            richTextBox1.Focus();
            findPos = richTextBox1.Find(s, findPos, RichTextBoxFinds.None);
            richTextBox1.Select(findPos, s.Length);
            findPos += textBox2.Text.Length +1;

            //i = richTextBox1.Find(s, i + s.Length, RichTextBoxFinds.None);
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No Occurences Found");
            findPos = 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do you search for the second occurence of the searched text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are searching from the start each time you press your button. If you make the variable `findPos` an instance method, it will search where you expect it to search from.

```
// make this a variable in the class instead of the method
private int findPos = 0;
void Button12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string searchText = textBox2.Text ;
    try
    {
        string s = textBox2.Text;
        richTextBox1.Focus();
        findPos = richTextBox1.Find(s, findPos, RichTextBoxFinds.None);
        richTextBox1.Select(findPos, s.Length);
        findPos += textBox2.Text.Length +1;

        //i = richTextBox1.Find(s, i + s.Length, RichTextBoxFinds.None);
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No Occurences Found");
        findPos = 0;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to reset findPos if you change the text in your textbox.